How include special characters like "@" and "." in a text box on an Android ".APK" using Robot class
`Hi everyone. I am currently busy with an Appium automation project. I am currently stuck on the login screen of the APK. I am making use of the Java Robot class instead of selectors, because the path locators are hidden in such a way, that Appium inspector is not seeing it. The Robot class does send values to the username and password textboxes, however I noticed that it does not include special characters like the @ symbol and period (.) symbol. The username is the email address of the user.
This is my code I currently have which works 100% fine. Is just the issue of including the "@" symbol and the "." . Assistance will be appreciated. Thanks.`
public void setUsername(String username) {

        String currentDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.out.println("Current working directory: " + currentDirectory);

        try {
            int xCoordinate = 1459;
            int yCoordinate = 686;

            PointerInput finger = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH,"finger");
            Sequence tap = new Sequence(finger,1);
              tap.addAction(finger.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(0),PointerInput.Origin.viewport(),xCoordinate,yCoordinate));
            tap.addAction(finger.createPointerDown(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));
            tap.addAction(finger.createPointerUp(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));
            driver.perform(Arrays.asList(tap));

            Thread.sleep(4500);
            Robot robot = new Robot();

//            Works 100%
            for(char c : username.toCharArray()) {
                    int keyCode = getKeyCodeForChar(c);

                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Key code not found for character: " + c);

                    }

                    robot.keyPress(keyCode);
                    robot.keyRelease(keyCode);

//                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
//                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

                }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());

        }

    }


 public static int getKeyCodeForChar(char c){

        if(c >= '0' && c <= '9'){
            return KeyEvent.VK_0 + (c - '0');

        }else if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'){
            return KeyEvent.VK_A + (c - 'A');

        }else if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            return KeyEvent.VK_A + (c - 'a');

        }else if(c >= '@'){
            return KeyEvent.VK_AT + (c - '@');

        }else{
            return KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED;

        }

    }

